# ServerName in Apache2 logs

Tags: apache, ubuntu-16.04, apache2.4

I'm running apache2.4 on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine.
I have set up two Document root each with different ServerName in /etc/apache2/sites-available. Is there anyway to configure the logs to capture the ServerName too because I want to know to site the request is made or log the DocumentRoot.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.first.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/first
        LogFormat "%{Host}i%U%q" combined
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have set www.first.com to 127.0.0.1 in the same Ubunutu box and I'm trying to access www.first.com from the same box. The access.log still don't show www.first.com.
Any thoughts ?

Comment: Do you need both virtual hosts logged into the same files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My grasp from the [Custom Log Formats](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats) chapter is that you need the `%v` format string:

```
%v  The canonical ServerName of the server serving the request.
```

That means that a virtual host like:

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias example.net
ServerAlias example.org
```

... always gets logged as `example.com` no matter the entry point.

Also, the standard `combined` nickname is this:

```
"%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\""
```

You're certainly allowed to edit it but it's kind of confusing. You may want to assign a different name, as in the [LogFormat](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat) example:

```
LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" vhost_common
```